# Why is 1200 being recognized as a valid date with moment?

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

Hi I am looping through an array of objects and trying to change the values to true if the value is validated as a date but some values are being hit as well. I put examples of some values below.

```
const data1 = 1200;
const date = '2022-05-24T14:52:30.250Z';
console.log(moment(data1, moment.ISO_8601, true).isValid()); < --- expected to be false but returns true
console.log(moment(date, moment.ISO_8601, true).isValid()); < --- returns true
```

why is this? Thank you for the help.

Comment: Why don't you log the single components: year, month, day, etc?

Comment: Javascript is not a typed language and it has a lot of weird automatic conversions. Why moment doesn't check the type before checking the format is to me unknown (the core of your question), but because it is not more recommended to use moment, I assume they have a design flaws (which is not easily to correct).

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi—is has nothing to do with type conversion. There are many ways to represent a date, so the ECMAScript *Date* constructor accepts different types, and so does moment.js. The value's type is not converted, though processing is different depending on the type (strings are parsed, numbers are treated as time values, etc.). Read [*the spec*](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-date).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the first value passed to *moment* is a number, it's treated as a time value, the format argument is ignored. Any number in the range ±8.64e15 will be treated as representing a valid date.

The number 1200 will be treated as 1200 milliseconds after the ECMAScript epoch of 1 Jan 1970 UTC, so 1970-01-01T00:00:01.200Z, which is a valid date.

```js
console.log(moment(1200).utc().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.3/moment.min.js"></script>
```